# Elasticsearch and PHP. Query and match certain fields, but return all fields

Tags: php, elasticsearch

My documents, that I store in Elasticsearch have a lot of fields, like `id`, `id_obj`, `color` etc. However, when I query data, as a response I get only `id` field and those fields that I match against. The query looks like so:

```
 $params = [
        'index' => $index_name,
        'type' => $index_name . '_type',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'should' => [['match' => [ 'field1' => '12' ]],
                    ['multi_match' => [ 'query' => '345', 'fields' => ['field2', 'field3']]]]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

$res = $client->search($params);
```

As a result of the above query, I get only `id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3` fields inside `_source`. But I want to get all fields. By the way there is nothing special about `id_obj`, `color` etc. fields, they are all indexed and stored.

Comment: This is strange, which version of ES you are using? could you include the output `curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/_mapping/your_type'`?

Comment: I'm using the last version of ES. I've just downloded it. As for the output, it looks like so: `{"test_index":{"mappings":{"test_index_type":{"properties":{"field1":{"type":"text","analyzer":"standard"},"field2":{"type":"text","analyzer":"standard"},...,"id":{"type":"long"},"id_color":{"type":"text"},"id_obj":{"type":"integer"},"id_order":{"type":"long"}}}}}}`

Comment: As you can see, there are fields id_color, id_obj, id_order, but I do not see them when I query the index. I get just id, field1, field2 and field3.